# Simple animation in kivy

Tags: python, animation, kivy

I want to make myself a simple animation class for `kivy`. The code shown below should animate a line between `[x1, y1]` and `[x2, y2]`.

```
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics import Color, Line

class Animation():
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas  = canvas

    def line(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):
        with self.canvas:
            Color(0.2, 1, 1, 1)
            l = Line(points=[x1, y1], width=5)
            x_i = 0
            y_i = 0
            x_pos = list(range(x1, x2))
            y_pos = list(range(y1, y2))
            while x_i < len(x_pos) and y_i < len(y_pos):
                l.points += [x_pos[x_i], y_pos[y_i]]
                x_i += 1; y_i += 1
```

When I use this class in a simple script using kivy, this line shows up immediately after creating the window without any animation. So I want to put a time sleep in that `while` loop, but `time.sleep()` is not supported by kivy. What can I use instead?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

> time.sleep() is not supported by kivy

This is wrong, time.sleep works fine, it just doesn't do the thing you want.

Instead, use `Clock.schedule_interval` to schedule a function that updates the line points.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try it.